# AngularJs trying to passa a list inside a var to another var

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$scope.listaOcorrencias = TesteServico.getListaOcorrencia();
//This generate $scope.listaOcorrencias.list with data
//but if i try to read the $scope.listaOcorrencias.list give error
console.log($scope.listaOcorrencias.list);  //returns undefined
$scope.listaOcorrencia = $scope.listaOcorrencias.list; //undefined too
```

Really don´t know what to do.

`console.log($scope.listaOcorrencias)` returns:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
list: Array[1]
__proto__: Resource
```

the TesteServico.getListaOcorrencia():

```
return $resource('http://127.0.0.1:8080/teste/:classe/:action', {}, {
        getListaOcorrencia: { method: 'GET', params:{classe: 'Ocorrencia', action: 'listaDeAssuntos'}, headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' }
}
```

Comment: `console.log($scope.listaOcorrencias)` what is the output?

Comment: What does `TesteServico.getListaOcorrencia()` look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: It appears that you are getting back a promise, show the output from: TesteServico.getListaOcorrencia().then(function(list){console.log(list)});

Comment: the return of 

 TesteServico.getListaOcorrencia().then(function(list){console.log(list)});

is:

TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'then'

Comment: What does the data returned from the http call look like?